# PayPal for PhoneGap - Error in PaymentActivity.ENVIRONMENT_LIVE

Tags: android, cordova, paypal, phonegap-plugins

Im working on PayPal integration in Android with Phonegap Framework.

I have taken the code given in GitHub. Im getting an error in this line

[image]

> **private String environemnt = PaymentActivity.ENVIRONMENT_LIVE**;

I have checked out with many codes online but always ending up with an error in this line. 
Were those data members have been removed in the latest update of the code or have I missed out anything which solves this problem.

I see many people also dealing with the same problem. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the version of PhoneGap plugin you are using, but the environment constants changed in the underlying mobile SDK in version 2.x.  Try PaymentActivity.ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Matt Jacunski, I have doubt. If the environment constants has changed in the recent update, wont it throw an error in previously developed apps with Paypal Integration through Phonegap framework?

Comment: This is the repo you should use with version 2.0+ of the PayPal SDK: https://github.com/paypal/paypal-cordova-plugin.  See proper constant: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Cordova-Plugin/blob/master/src/android/PayPalMobileCordovaPlugin.java#L22